# Primefaces - Change background of tabView tabs

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, tabview

I am working with PrimeFaces and trying to edit the background color of my `tabView` menu items but am unable to do so. 
This is what is required:

[image]

I am adding the `styleClass` attribute in xhtml. (Writing "..." instead of the long lists of attribute values that are not relevant to the problem.)

```
<p:tabView styleClass="menu" value="..." dir="..." dynamic="true" activeIndex="...">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="..." />
        <p:tab >
            <div> .... </div>
        </p:tab> 
</p:tabView>
```

The html generated is:

```
<div id="tabView" class="..... menu">
<ul class="...." role="tablist">
    <li class="...." role="tab" aria-expanded="true">
        <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="...." role="tab" aria-expanded="true">
        <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="ui-tabs-panels">
    <div > ..... </div>
</div>
```

The class menu is defined as following. The commented lines are the ones I have tried but give different results than required.

```
.menu {
    font-family: Open Sans;
    /* first attempt:
    background-size: 5px; 
    background-color: #fff;
    */
    /* second attempt:
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFF 10px, #ebeff2 100%); 
    */  
    /* third attempt: 
    background-color: #fff;
    */
}
.menu ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url(../resources/images/menu_sep.png);
}
```

The output is this:

[image]

From what I understand, the problem is that the html generated applies my `menu` class to the `<div>` element, not the `<ul>`. Is there any way of adding this class to the `<ul>` tag? I have tried adding `styleClass="menu"` to the `<p:ajax>` and `<p:tab>` tags, but that does not work. 
The Primefaces version is 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to apply the style class to the `<ul />` element is to override the default *TabView* renderer. But i think this is a little bit excessive. Why not using the style class *menu* as an anchor only and create some style with a css selector like `.menu > ul` to style the list item under the `<div />` element like you already did with the `<li />` elements with your `.menu ul li` style?

Comment: Worked! Changed some attributes like padding and margins, the result is now exactly what I wanted.